# How to cast AnyObject to NSTaggedPointerString?

Tags: swift, foundation

I have a `NSDictionary` with keys of type `String` and values of type `AnyObject`.

When debugged, one of the values is of type `NSTaggedPointerString`.

When trying to convert the `AnyObject` to `NSTaggedPointerString` I get the following error:

> Use of undeclared type '`NSTaggedPointerString`'

Comment: Use cast it to NSString

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tagged pointer uses the object pointer to store the referenced value in the *object pointer itself*. There is a good explanation of how this works [here](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) but essentially in the case of an `NSTaggedPointerString` up to 60 bits of string data can be stored in a 64 bit pointer reducing the need to allocate and manage additional memory.

All of this is handled transparently for you by the Core Foundation framework for you so you can just cast it to `NSString`